# Could not read response to hello message from hook

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to type `sudo apt upgrade`. After that it gives me an error:

```
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-json-hook || true: Success
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1462776/edit) your question to include the Ubuntu release you are using?  Also, you have this tagged WSL, but you don't mention that in your question itself - For most tags, that's not really necessary, but WSL is such a "niche" that it can be useful to call it out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be experiencing the same problem mentioned in [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9269).  It seems to commonly occur with Ubuntu and WSL after upgrading to 22.10 Kinetic (although you don't mention your Ubuntu release in your question).  It may be related to a particular package or dependency, as one of the comments in that issue mentions Apache.

If that is your root issue, then the solution in that thread (modified slightly for safety) is:

```
sudo mv /etc/atp/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf /root/
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

It certainly sounds like an issue that should be [reported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), if someone can figure out the exact flow that can reproduce it.